# How to rename files by placing the number at the start of the filename

Tags: python

My task is:

- Write a program that would:

  - Find all txt `files` ending with number (like `tekstas5.txt`).
  - Rename them by placing the number at the start of the filename.

First one all good, but how to make another one?

Topic was: Regular expressions (regex) so I have to make it with `re.split`, `re.match`, etc.

For the first task I made

```
def find_files_re(directory, pattern): 
    files = [str(element) for element in list(Path(directory).rglob("./*"))]
    files = [element for element in files if re.search(pattern, element)]
    return files

bioa_dir = Path.joinpath(Path.home(), "Documents", "bioa", "data", "txt")
file_list = find_files_re(bioa_dir, r"\d+.*txt$")
file_list
```

second

```
arr_txt = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".txt")]
print (arr_txt)
```

['tekstas1.txt', 'tekstas7.txt', 'tekstas5.txt', 'tekstas9.txt']

after it all im trying doest work

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: share your approach and what have you tried unless you want the community here to do your homework :)

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
`def get_digits` defined to get number from string,`os.listdir()` list files in your desire directory and `os.rename` rename file with adding number a the beginning of filename
`path='./files/'` is the folder that files located

```
import os
def get_digits(str1):
    c = ""
    for i in str1:
        if i.isdigit():
            c += i
            return c
path='./files/'
dir_list=os.listdir(path)


for i in range(0,len(dir_list)):
    tmp=str(dir_list[i])
    os.rename(path+tmp,path+str(get_digits(tmp))+tmp)
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over the indexes of the list, instead of the list elements?

Comment: to change each file name one by one, need to find digit in each element, Please if you have idea edit the code to be more useful @JoshuaNixon

Comment: that one look great but as i said before i need to use regex for this task

Comment: @JoshuaNixon you code edition rejected by community, by the way it was great and useful. please post it as answer